# How to run a thread in the backgound of a jsf website?

Tags: java, database, jsf, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to do the following: I have a website and there are jsf pages im my website. In some of the pages i have a **DataTable** that is filled with some values from the **database**. I want to **update** this **database** periodically so that the values in those tables will also change. When i searched i found out that i need to use quartz for this. I am thinking of making a managed bean to fill the tables from database, and then get the values from the database at that bean. Here is my example code:

```
 <h:form>
        <rich:extendedDataTable style=" column-width: 174px; width:174px;" value="#{exchangeRates.values}" var="values"  id="accountsTable"  styleClass="accountsTable" headerClass="accountsTableHeader" rowClasses="accountsTableOddRow,accountsTableEvenRow"  >

            <rich:column width="40px;">
                <f:facet name="header">Currency</f:facet>
                   #{values.type}
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column width="45px;">
                <f:facet name="header">Alış</f:facet>
                   #{values.buy}
            </rich:column >
            <rich:column  width="45px;" >
                <f:facet name="header">Satış</f:facet>
                   #{values.sell}
            </rich:column>

        </rich:extendedDataTable>
```

and the managed bean for this jsf page:

```
private String value;
private ArrayList<Money> values = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<Money> getValues() {
    try {
        getCurrentExchangeValue();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ExchangeRates.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return values;
}

private void getCurrentExchangeValue() throws IOException {
     //GET THE VALUES FROM THE DATABASE AND
     //FILL THE  "values" ArrayList
}


public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

My datatable in the page is succesfully filled with this code but not updated periodically.
My question is, where should i put the "update database manually" code? Should it be on this managed bean in another function? I fell like i need another thread running in the bacground and whenever something like #{values.buy} calls the managed bean the thread should update database. How can i do it?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I think my question was not clear so here is the summary: I want the database to be updated periodically, like every 10 minutes. Since i fill my datatable from the database, whenever a user browses the page in which this datatable is viewed, the table is filled with the latest updated database values.

Comment: Do you need the database to be updated all the time, or just when a user is viewing the page? Do you need the values to be updated automatically while the user is viewing it or just when the user reloads the page?

Comment: @Simon i want to update database all the time, like every 20 minutes regardless of people viewing the page in which datatable stays. I want the values in db updated automatically so that if a user views the page in which datatable stays, the table is filled with the latest updated values

Comment: Datatable view can be updated while the page is viewed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do update the database automatically with the datatable contents, you need to make periodic AJAX requests to the server.

Using multi-threading on server side code won't help unless and until you make a request to the server.

To send periodic AJAX requests, you can use JS timer and richfaces AJAX support component.

Start the timer like this ...

```
var pingInterval = 1000; // 1 sec
setInterval(contactServer, pingInterval);

function contactServer(){
    // send request to server 
}
```

You can refer [this](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/06/using-richfaces-a4jjsfunction-sending-an-ajax-request-from-any-javascript/) for various option regarding sending AJAX request using Richfaces.

Comment: Thanks but if i update datatable manually nothing happens because the values in the database are still the same. I am trying to update the "database", where i keep some values that nedd to change periodically

Comment: When you send a request to the managed bean, from managed bean you need to query the database for latest results.

Comment: You want to update the database ? Are you looking to keep the database in sync with the datatable, in case contents in the datatable are changed ?

Comment: oh i think i had to explain more, yes, i will need to query database and will query it but i am not updating the database manually, i grab some data from a webpage html and put this values in my database.

Comment: so if database is updated periodically, when the page loads the table is filled with the last updated values of the database

Comment: In that case, you can simply provide some update button on your webpage and bind that button with some action listener on managed bean. In this action listener, update the database with latest values from the datatable. This will make sure the datatable and the database are in sync.

Comment: ah yes, that would be a solution but isn't there any way to do this without a button, just like in every 20 minustes?

Comment: Another solution would be the one I mentioned, while sending AJAX request to the server, send the contents of datatable as well. For this you need to use the [process](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html_single/#process) and [rerender](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html_single/#DecideWhatToChange) attributes

Answer (score 0):

Managed bean is not required for updating data base in background. Its all related to business logic that server should handle.

You could start a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) during context initialization or with an Application Scoped Bean Post construct method.

View Scoped data table can be refreshed with latest changes in db.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem some time ago and came to the following conclusions:

As for automatically updating the page in the users web browser you can use ajax.

As for updating the database, what alternatives you have depend on what environment you are working in (web-server/servlet container and frameworks).

If you are using **JPA** to do your database work then you'll want to get a hold of your `EntityManager` which can't be injected into a quartz thread. Also in threads that are managed by quartz you won't be able to access the JSF **context** (nor CDI context if you use that). If you're on a web server with **EJB 3.1** then you can use `@Schedule`. That way you'll be able to inject your `EntityManager` and get JSF/CDI context although it doesn't do everything that quartz does in terms of scheduling. If you connect directly to the database then quartz is a very good choise.
If you need to have access to the JSF/CDI context and don't have EJB 3.1 (or if you need some functionallity that quartz has but `@Schedule` lacks then you can have a quartz job that calls a web service (for instance JAX-RS) which will get access to the context.

To summarize:

**If you need JPA or JSF/CDI context and can use `@Schedule`:**
Update the database in a `@Schedule` job.

**If you need JPA but can't use `@Schedule` or need advanced scheduling:**
Set up a quartz job that calls a webservice and have the webservice update the database.

**If you connect to your database directly:**
Use a quartz job and update the database directly from there.